# Youtube Data API v3 nextPageToken not working

Tags: youtube-data-api

So I've just started to use the Youtube Data API to get comments from youtube videos. My program has been working until I tried to use the next page token to get more comments. So it first calls the normal URL without the `&pageToken=***`and then the next time it loops back it calls it with that but returns an error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.parameter",
    "reason": "invalidPageToken",
    "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "pageToken"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token."
 }
}
```

My program, when calling the first time would get the key returned and save it in a variable for the next time it calls the new url. Yes, I have verified that my variable holds a key. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Please provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](minimal reproducible example). You aren't providing the videoId nor the problematic pageToken...

Answer (score 1):

You forget **playlistId** it's required , example :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=3&playlistId=PLw6Y5u47CYq47oDw63bMqkq06fjuoK_GJ&pageToken=EAAaBlBUOkNBTQ&key=['api_key']&nextPageToken=EAAaBlBUOkNBTQ
```

[take a look on api documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuXaR.png)